# Fontawesome 5+ icons not showing up

Tags: sass, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to import fontawesome v5.6.3 free version to my project. I'm using its scss version. but icons are not showing in the page. i checked and figured that "font-family" property of css does not exist for font-awesome.

Comment: Please include some examples of your setup, link to site, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As i mentioned, i figured that the problem is that the "font-family" property is not exists. so i checked the scss files. we have 3 types of icons in fontawesome 5+ with the following font-families:

- brands (font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands')
- regular (font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free')
- solid (font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free')

i figured that they are not imported in **fontawesome.scss**.

## Solution

all you have to do is open **fontawesome.scss** file, then import these 3 files in it:

```
@import 'brands';
@import 'regular';
@import 'solid';
```

That's all.